# Assigning ArrayList<List<Integer>> with an ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

Why can I not assign an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` into an `ArrayList<List<Integer>>` like below:

```
ArrayList<List<Integer>> x = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Aren't all ArrayLists Lists and therefore where I can put a List, I can also place an ArrayList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because if `x` is typed as an `ArrayList<List<Integer>>`, then you can stuff any kind of list into `x`, so this should be legal:

```
x.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());
```

But if `x` is actually an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`, that shouldn't be allowed.

This is allowed:

```
ArrayList<? extends List<Integer>> x = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

But with that definition of `x`, you won't be able to actually put anything into `x`.

Answer (score 1):

If this were legal, you could do the following:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> y = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<List<Integer>> x = y;  // Compiler error! Pretend it's OK, though.

x.add(new LinkedList<>());  // Fine, because a LinkedList<Integer> is a List<Integer>
```

but then this would fail:

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = y.get(0);  // ClassCastException!
```

because the first element of `y` is a `LinkedList`, not an `ArrayList`.

You can assign `y` to `x` if the type of `x` is

```
ArrayList<? extends List<Integer>>`
```

because you couldn't then add anything (other than literal `null`) to that list, hence the `ClassCastException` wouldn't occur.